# How to Make Epoch Time which is there in the middle of my log as @timestamp in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have the below log

1 iCEXnXWuShGYRlDbHEADlQ 1 3 sara482 1573151463576 1.5 13.8 0.0 0 0 62.6||

my grok pattern is below

"message", "%{NUMBER:log_Level} (?[^\s]+) %{NUMBER:mcty} %{NUMBER:agty} (?[^\s]+) %{INT:ts} %{NUMBER:cpu} %{NUMBER:mem} %{NUMBER:swap} %{NUMBER:diskr} %{NUMBER:diskw} %{NUMBER:diskc}\|\|%{GREEDYDATA:appc}"

How can I make filed ts as @timestamp, currently if I check the field mappings for the index these logs getting stored in Elastic Search, the ts filed is mapped as string, I am able to mutate rest of fields as Num/Float however only field ts I am not able to convert or match as @timestamp.

I have tried converting the filed as UNIX/UNIX_MS however my logstash is breaking if I try map ito any thing other than NUM/INT

Answer (score 1):

you can add this to logstash config:

```
date {
  match => [ "ts", "UNIX" ]
  target => "ts"
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, still when I refresh the mappings in kibana I still see ts filed as string only, it is not detecting it as date.

Comment: I have tried mapping it to %{NUMBER:ts:int} and now i see that ts is changed number, I will apply date settings and check if it works.